# Rotations around distinct points in the plane cannot be commutative

Tags: matrices

I am trying to prove that given two isometry on the plane that consist of rotations of the plane around distinct points contain a translation in their group (please see [Groups containing two rotations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488325/groups-containing-two-rotations))

I have showed that they need to be in the kernel and everything but cannot show that $fg$ is not equal to $gf$.

[image]

I know that $a$ and $p(a)$ have the same length as orthogonal operators preserve lengths. It makes sense that they don’t equal but how do we know for sure? So basically is: $a+b’=b+a’$ where $a$ and $a’$ have the same length same goes for $b$. How to show this is not possible for non trivial vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to also assume that $f$ and $g$ are *nontrivial* rotations, or else it is indeed true that $fg = gf$.

So, given that $f$ is a nontrivial rotation about the point $p$ and $g$ is a nontrivial rotation about the point $q$, and $p \neq q$, why don't we check what $fg$ and $gf$ do to the points $p$ and $q$ themselves?

Since $g(q) = q$, we have
$$
fg(q) = f(g(q)) = f(q)
$$

But since $f$ is not centered at $q$, we have that $f(q) \neq q$. Therefore
$$
gf(q) = g(f(q)) \neq f(q)
$$
using the fact that $g$ is a nontrivial rotation, and hence $g(x) \neq x$ for all  $x \neq q$. Thus, we conclude that
$$
fg(q) = f(q) \neq gf(q) 
$$
$$
\implies fg \neq gf
$$

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful